# Custom rake task can't access ActiveRecord data immediately after rake db tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, rake-task

I have a batch of rake tasks that run sequentially:

```
task :batch_tasks => :environment do
  Rake::Task["db:drop"].execute
  Rake::Task["db:create"].execute
  Rake::Task["db:migrate"].execute
  Rake::Task["db:seed"].execute
  Rake::Task["db:test:prepare"].execute
  Rake::Task["custom_task_1"].execute
end
```

Here's what's in custom_task_1:

```
task :custom_task_1 => :environment do
  puts "begin custom task"
  orders = Order.all #three records
  orders.each do |order|
    puts "Do something to Order\n"
  end
  puts "end custom task"
end
```

When I run the above batch process, here's what happens:

```
rake batch_tasks
begin custom task
end custom task
```

But if I run the custom task AFTER the batch process, here's what happens:

```
rake custom_task_1
begin custom task
Do something to Order
Do something to Order
Do something to Order
end custom task
```

One thing to note, when I run debugger on `rake batch_tasks` with a breakpoint after `rake db:seed`, a check on `eval Order.all` returns an empty array `[]`. However, `Order.all` does have data immediately *after* all of the rake tasks are finished.

What am I missing about rake db:seed and having access to ActiveRecord data in the next task called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the quick fix was to move the `db:test:prepare` line to the end of the batch.

I believe the problem stemmed from the environment being switched from `development` to `test` and then the custom task was running in the last environment, which then had an empty test database.

The `db:seed` command probably switches the environment back to dev and the custom task runs against the correct database.

```
task :batch_tasks => :environment do
  Rake::Task["db:drop"].execute
  Rake::Task["db:create"].execute
  Rake::Task["db:migrate"].execute
  Rake::Task["db:seed"].execute
  Rake::Task["custom_task_1"].execute
  Rake::Task["db:test:prepare"].execute # <-- Moved after all other tasks
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As mu is too short suggested, this is related to the need to reload models before using them in migrations.   The reason for this is that all of your rake tasks run in a common environment, ie, it only loads rails once.  As such, the table definitions may already be established.  You will probably have to use `reset_column_information` to load the new values.

Alternately, the sequence of tasks you are doing look like they should be run independently, which could be a good use case for capistrano or thor.

Comment: In this scenario, wouldn't the rake db:seed fail? It's succeeding, the subsequent rake tasks just can't access the data for some reason.

Comment: found the issue...your answer wasn't the solution, but it did cause me to mess around with the code in a different way.